# Bash: capture stdError from looped stream

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr

I have a cpp executable (`mycat`) that continuously read a looped audio stream from the shared memory and pipes the data to stdOut and the metadata information to stdErr. `mycat` pipes out 12 lines for every entry of the audio stream, containing the metadata information, looking like this:

```
0x1 (TimeStamp) 12Bytes:2956 +     6793/(47999+1) (0.141521) delta= 0+    1536/(47999+1) (0.032000) 2956.151418 -9.898ms 2016.04.04 16:06:37.700
0x4 (ReferenceTime) 12Bytes:2956 +  6156972/(26999999+1) (0.228036) delta= 0+ 1618519/(26999999+1) (0.059944) 2956.151426 76.610ms 2016.04.04 16:06:37.700
0x6 (ProcessDelay) 4Bytes: 64 (0x40)
0x7 (ClockAccuracy) 8Bytes: offset=0.000ppm (+-0.000ppm)
0xb (ClockId) 8Bytes: 01 00 00 00 42 22 01 00
0x20001 (SampleRate) 4Bytes: 48000 (0xbb80)
0x20002 (Channels) 4Bytes: 6 (0x6)
0x20003 (PcmLevel) 24Bytes: -21307 -20348 -31737 -42427 -28786 -26525
0x20004 (PcmPeak) 24Bytes: -14366 -13360 -25203 -39427 -19067 -21307
0x2000e (DolbyDpMetadata) 39352Bytes:
Linear Time: 2956 +     6793/(47999+1) (0.141521) delta= 0+    1536/(47999+1) (0.032000)
2016.04.04 16:06:37.700 update: slot=0xe2840 validTo=0x3d1dd180 shmT=0x3d195200 (delta=294784) doffset=0xec2c0 msize=39552 dsize=18432 type=0x20001 (PCMS16) data bytes: df f4 f2 fc
```

What I want is a bash script that:

1) launch `mycat` eg. `./mycat shm_name > /dev/null`.

2) reads stdErr from `mycat` till the 12th line no matter where it started.

2.1) Eventually store the 12 line into a variable (this is optional)

3) immedialy kills `mycat` after the 12th line, so that the bash script can continue without being annoyed by the outcoming stdError.

4) Read the value of the line "Channels" (in this case 6) and store it to a variable named "channels"

5) Read the value of the line "SampleRate" (in this case 48000) and store it the a variable named "rate"

is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out an elegant solution:

```
while read -r line;                                         # Read mycat line by line
do
    if echo "$line" | grep -qi "SampleRate"; then           # Search for line containing string 'SampleRate'
        rate="${line#*:}";                                  # Remove all charachters till ':' 
        rate="${rate%(*}";                                  # Remove all charachters from '('
        rate="$(echo -e "${rate}" | tr -d '[[:space:]]')"   # Remove all tralling withespace
    elif echo "$line" | grep -qi "Channels"; then
        channels="${line#*:}";
        channels="${channels%(*}";
        channels="$(echo -e "${channels}" | tr -d '[[:space:]]')"
    fi

    if [ -n "$channels"  ] && [ -n "$rate"  ]; then         # If both variables 'channels' and 'rate' are not empty kill the while loop
        break;
    fi
done < <(./mycat $shm_name  2>&1 > /dev/null)           # Mycat is processed into a while loop, standard Error is redirected to standard Output ( 2>&1 )

echo "Found datarate: $rate"
echo "Found channels: $channels"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect stderr with `mycat shm_name > /dev/null 2>/path/to/file`. You can kill mycat with `killall mycat` when the time comes. For storing the variables, you want `export channels =`, same pattern with rate. You can find those with `grep`. I'm not sure how to wait for exactly twelve lines, though.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to redirect STDERR to STDOUT, and have STDOUT go to null.

```
mycat 2>&1 >/dev/null | parsing_script
```

Then you need a parsing script to collect your data

```
 #!/bin/bash

declare -a data=()
count=1
while read line; do
   data+=( "$line
   ")
   ((count++))

   string=$(echo $line|sed 's/.*(\(.[A-Za-z]*\)).*/\1/')
   case $string in
      SampleRate) rate=$(echo $line|sed 's/.*: \(.[0-9]*\) .*/\1/')
        ;;
      Channels) channels=$(echo $line|sed 's/.*: \(.[0-9]*\) .*/\1/')
        ;;
      *) true;;
   esac
   if [[ $count -gt 12 ]]; then
      break
   fi
done <&0

echo $channels
echo $rate
```

I echo'd the values, but you can redirect them to a file, format them, etc.  Also, ${data[@]} contains your metadata.  Since you are piping, I'm reading in from STDIN, but it could be more robust if you want to tweak it.